# Apply a function to all pairs in the same group

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to apply a function to all pairs of items in the same group e.g.

Example input:

```
Group  Item   Value  
A      1       89   
A      2       76  
A      3       2  
B      4       21  
B      5       10
```

The desired output is a vector of the function output for all items in the same group.

e.g. for arguments sake if the function was:

```
addnums=function(x,y){  
  x+y  
}
```

Then the desired output would be:

`165, 91, 78, 31`

I have tried to do this using summarize in the dplyr package but this can only be used if the output is a single value.

Comment: Actually it isn;t te duplicate of question that you provided. He wants sums of each pair in group, not sum of the group.

Comment: yes, reopened the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Missed that. Thanks @RonakShah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `split` `Value` for each `Group` and then use `combn` to calculate `sum` for each pair.

```
sapply(split(df$Value, df$Group), combn, 2, sum)

#$A
#[1] 165  91  78

#$B
#[1] 31
```

If needed as one vector we can use `unlist`.

```
unlist(sapply(split(df$Value, df$Group), combn, 2, sum), use.names = FALSE)
#[1] 165  91  78  31
```

---

If you are interested in `tidyverse` solution using the same logic we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_split(Group) %>%
  map(~combn(.x %>% pull(Value), 2, sum)) %>% flatten_dbl

#[1] 165  91  78  31
```

Comment: I tried to do this by myself, however it doesn't work properly. Why `group_by()` doesn't work in this case? `data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  {apply(combn(Value, m=2), 2, sum)}`

Comment: @Adamm hmmm...I am not sure using `apply` would be the right choice here.

Comment: Thanks, that is great! However, I can't quite figure out how to modify it to use with my custom function addnums rather than the built in function sum.

Comment: @Helen you could use it like `sapply(split(df$Value, df$Group), function(x) combn(x, 2, function(y) addnums(y[1], y[2])))`

Answer (score 2):

We can use a group by option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, combn(Value, 2, FUN = sum), Group]
#   Group  V1
#1:     A 165
#2:     A  91
#3:     A  78
#4:     B  31
```

If we want to use `addnums` from the OP's post

```
setDT(df1)[, combn(Value, 2, FUN = function(x) addnums(x[1], x[2])), Group]
 #  Group  V1
#1:     A 165
#2:     A  91
#3:     A  78
#4:     B  31
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(Sum = list(combn(Value, 2, FUN = sum)))  %>% 
  unnest
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Group   Sum
#  <chr> <int>
#1 A       165
#2 A        91
#3 A        78
#4 B        31
```

Using `addnums`

```
df1 %>% 
 group_by(Group) %>%
 summarise(Sum = list(combn(Value, 2, FUN = 
         function(x) addnums(x[1], x[2])))) %>% 
 unnest
```

---

Or using `base R` with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Value ~ Group, df1, FUN = function(x) combn(x, 2, FUN = sum))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), Item = 1:5, 
    Value = c(89L, 76L, 2L, 21L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well but it's quite important for me to use the addnums function that I defined rather than sum, is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: @Helen Thanks, I updated the post.  I would keep the group info column to identify the values correctly